# Duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa, facebook-sdk-4.0

I got the following error when trying to build my app: `35 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64`

[image]

This error only started after I tried to implement the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/).

Any thoughts as to what I could do to resolve this error?

Comment: Set Excluded arch's in pod build settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `x86_64` to the Excluded Architectures solved the issue.

[image]