azure devops React native IOS build RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found error
i get this error in my devops pipeline for IOS build of react native app
RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found

/Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/MyNewApp/AppDelegate.h:1:9:
'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found
CompileC
/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyNewApp-ajfktijvrkpgmscslwbprnszgveb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyNewApp.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyNewApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o
/Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/MyNewApp/AppDelegate.mm normal x86_64
objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target
'MyNewApp' from project 'MyNewApp') (1 failure)

Can someone help me out?
pipeline def below:
trigger:
- Integration
variables:
- group: Mobile
pool:
  vmImage: macos-latest
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  clean: true
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '20.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
- script: |
    yarn install
  displayName: 'yarn install and build'
- script: |
    yarn bundle:ios
  displayName: 'RN build'
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'DistCertfr2024.p12'
    certPwd: '$(AppleCertPassword)'
    keychain: 'temp'
    deleteCert: true
- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'fr2024ProvisioningV1.mobileprovision'
    removeProfile: true
- script: |
    cd ios
    pod install
    xcodebuild -showsdks
  displayName: 'Install CocoaPods dependencies'
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    sdk: 'iphonesimulator' 
    scheme: 'MyNewApp'
    packageApp: true
    signingOption: 'manual'
    provisioningProfileName: 'fr2024ProvisioningV1'
    configuration: 'Release'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'ios/MyNewApp.xcodeproj'
    exportPath: 'output'
    destinationPlatformOption: default
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    Contents: '**/*.ipa'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    OverWrite: true
    flattenFolders: true
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'ios'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

yarn bundle:ios   script translates to:
"bundle:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/MyNewApp/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'"


Can you build the project successfully on your local machine?  What is the Xcode version on your local machine ? You need to share the Pipeline definition in the question. This will be helpful to investigate the issue furhter.

I have checked the YAML sample you shared. Can you confirm if the issue exists in the Xcode build step. If yes,  you can try to set the .xcworkspace file instead of .xcodeproj file in the Xcode task -> xcWorkspacePath field

Yes, Kevin, that did help it move further. Thanks !
Now its some linker issue, with duplicate symbols. Though the titled issue is resolved, i would like to keep adding other subsequent build errors in my effort to get this resolved.
New error is:
❌  ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
 Will add log details , in hope of getting some ideas here.


ok, i see some answers to the duplicate symbol issue at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76171249/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-under-xcode-in-react-native
will give it a try

Thanks for your update. Glad to know that the suggestion can give you help. For the current issue in the question, I have added an answer to share the solution. For the latest issue: ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 , you can try to exclude the x86_64 in xcconfig file(add content: EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*] = x86_64). Here is the tickets about the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692735/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512823/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-after-xcode-8-0-update


/Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/MyNewApp/AppDelegate.h:1:9: 'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found

To solve this issue, we need to set the .xcworkspace file instead of .xcodeproj file in the Xcode task -> xcWorkspacePath field.
For example:
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    sdk: 'iphonesimulator' 
    scheme: 'MyNewApp'
    packageApp: true
    signingOption: 'manual'
    provisioningProfileName: 'fr2024ProvisioningV1'
    configuration: 'Release'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'ios/MyNewApp.xcworkspace'
    exportPath: 'output'
    destinationPlatformOption: default

